# In Gatling generate POST body dynamically based on a string input

Tags: split, gatling

I am very new to Gatling and Scala. I am trying to dynamically generate an XML file that will be used as the body of a request. The content of the XML file depends on a string value obtained as an environment variable or from the properties file.

```
    val applicationNames = "Math,Science,English"
```

The template XML should look like

```
    <applications>
        <application_id>Math</application_id>
        <application_id>Science</application_id>
        <application_id>English</application_id>
    </applications>
```

I tried string split, list and also csv feeder. Nothing seems to work. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide examples of the actual code and current output for what youve tried already, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number applications can be different each time. For example: val applicationNames = "Math,Science" or val applicationNames = "Math,Science,English,Spanish,History"